# Can't get conditional syntax correct

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, conditional, if-condition

Have [Tier] column with choice values of 0,1,2,3.

```
If [Tier] = 0 calculated column should = 0
If [Tier] = 1 calculated column should = 4
If [Tier] = 2 calculated column should = 24
If [Tier] = 3 calculated column should = 48
```

Can get to work for 2 values using the following syntax but not for 4 values:

```
=IF(OR([Tier]="1",[Tier]="2"),"4","24")
```

Comment: Thank you for the assist.  I went with the Choose option but the "" are definitely required.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
=CHOOSE([Tier]+1,0,4,24,48)
```

Option 2:

```
=IF(Tier=0,0,
     IF(Tier=1,4,
        IF(Tier=2,24,
             IF(Tier=3,48)
        )
      )
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 given in @Mike Smith's answer will work fine.

But there is small problem with his Option 2. You will need to modify the formula in option 2 like below:

```
=IF([Tier]="0",0,
        IF([Tier]="1",4,
            IF([Tier]="2",24,
                IF([Tier]="3",48)
            )
        )
    )
```

Note the quotes(`"`) used in formula for comparison.

**References**:

1. [CHOOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-function-e4b61fbc-40a4-4fe2-8b9c-c5e7a51fdbbe).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

**Calculated Column settings you want to use**:

[image]

Comment: I like the Choose option.  Never would have got that syntax.  Works perfectly!. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. As this answer helped your, please upvote and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).